# SQL Server compare date in bigint with current date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've a date/time field stored as BIGINT in the database. I need to retrieve records where the date in the database is older than 30 days from current date. I tried the following and it works.

Is there a better/simpler way to accomplish it?

```
select 
    datediff(day, CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(s, dateInBigint / 1000, '19700101'), 102),
                  CONVERT(date, getdate(),102));
```

e.g.:

```
select 
   datediff(day, CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(s, 1348986702000 / 1000, '19700101'), 102),
                 CONVERT(date, getdate(), 102));
```

Comment: why are you storing a `date` field as a `bigint`?

Comment: What is the meaning of the values in your example?

Comment: Usually we store dates using the `DATE` or `DATETIME` data types. I have to agree with @bluefeet - why on earth are you storing these as `BIGINT`? What do you think you're gaining by doing this? You already have some idea of what you're losing...

Comment: @bluefeet/Aaran - I don't have a clue of why they use BIGINT for storing dates but don't have a control over those.
@Tim - '1348986702000' in the example is a sample date that is stored in the database. Other numbers are used to convert it to a user-friendly date

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
   select  
        datediff(day, CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(ms, dateInBigint, '19700101'), 102), 
                      CONVERT(date, getdate(),102));
```

It might be a little faster.

Comment: Received error - 'Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int'
select  datediff(day, CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(ms, 1348986702000, '19700101'), 102), CONVERT(date, getdate(),102));     
                      
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int

Comment: 1348986702000 is too big for an int - looks like your original slect is the only way to go - your dates are the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01 - they are rather large numbers :)